# Don't append to last element of Set (StringBuffer)

Tags: set, append, stringbuffer

This is probably a simple enough solution. I am use a StringBuffer to create a String from all the elements of a Set (WardenSet). But I don't want a comma at the end of the last element. here is my code

```
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (String s : WardenSet) {

        sb.append(s + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(wardenInitials = sb.toString());
```

CURRENT OUTPUT: MD, BH,

WANTED OUTPUT: MD, BH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use an explicit iterator.

```
sb = new StringBuffer();
Iterator it = WardenSet.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String s = (String) it.next();
    sb.append(s);
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
System.out.println(wardenInitials = sb.toString());
```

Also, it's a good idea to replace StringBuffer with [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) unless you're going to have multiple threads using it.

If you're using Java 8, you can use [StringJoiner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
System.out.println(new StringJoiner(", ").join(WardenSet).toString());
```

If you're using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on(", ").join(WardenSet).toString());
```